# Sequelize - Does deleting a table mean only a migration or is it all references to it

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working on a sequelize controlled app. We decided that one of the tables was no longer needed and we want to delete it. To do this, do I simply run a migration to remove the table and any constraints or do I need to remove all references to that table in the app?

Comment: it looks like this question is not about Sequelize at all. It's all about DB structure. The same question you might ask about a table without mentioning Sequelize at all. What would happen if you drop a table with all references to it? It depends on what these references are: either they are from other tables TO the table or the other way around. And it could depend on what type of DBMS you have as well